# byte[] в Image source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно задать `Image source` передав ему `byte[]`? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MemoryStream byteStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.StreamSource = byteStream;
image.EndInit();
xamlImage.Source = image;
```